# How to determine angle and center of rotation with y' coordinates unknown

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, imagej

I have a set of 20 known points of coordinates {x,y} which is submitted to a rigid rotation (and small translation) of unknown center and angle.

Of the result I know each 20 points destination {x',?}, where the y' coordinate is unknown.

Using Matlab, there are methods to calculate a rigid transformations when both the initial body and its transformation are known.

I am thinking of testing couples {Theta,Xc,Zc} until the result is satisfying enough (the ranges for the parameters are relatively small), but this is going to be resource intensive.

I would be thankful if you could point me to a more elegant existing solution, or even if my approach is possible at all.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you show your effort? Take a look at this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have affine transformation

```
P * [A] = P'
```

For your case affine matrix contains four unknown values - Cos(Fi), Sin(Fi) (they are not really independent), XTerm and YTerm, where

```
XTerm = RotCenterX * (1 - Cos(Fi)) + RotCenterY * Sin(Fi) + ShiftX
```

You can build system of equations

```
XTerm + X(i) * Cos(Fi) - Y[i] * Sin(Fi) = X'(i)
```

and solve it with SVD-method for unknowns `Cos(Fi), Sin(Fi), XTerm`

or just choose non-degenerated subset of equations and solve it by any method (Gauss etc)

Note that solution might not exist (degenerated case)

**Edit:**
Then you can substitute `Cos(Fi)` and `Sin(Fi)` in `XTerm` equation but **cannot get three unknowns** (`RotCenterX, RotCenterY, ShiftX`) from a single equation (just estimate them). And there are no means to get `ShiftY` from given data.

Comment: I get the main idea. Though I do not understand what is XTerm in regard to ShiftX? In your second equation, XTerm seems to replace ShiftX?

Comment: No, XTerm consists of some parts - rotation-depending one and shift after rotation. Problem is that we cannot separate these parts. Even we have not shift, we have only one equation for RotCenterX, RotCenterY